# can access active admin/users on local but not production

Tags: heroku, activeadmin

ok so I can get to active admin on local and my site just fine - within active admin I have the options to select from Pins or Users (my two models) on local,  can see all of the pins and users in the db just fine. However, live (heroku) I can access active admin barnpix.com/admin and clicking on pins works just fine ..however when I click users I get a generic heroku error... please help why does this work in local but not live?

```
Omrails::Application.routes.draw do




  get "pages/tagz"

  get "pages/about"
  get "posts/show"
  get "posts/destroy"

root :to => 'pins#index'


  get 'tags/:tag' , to: 'pins#index', as: :tag


get "posts", to: "posts#index"



  resources :posts
  resources :pins
  get "users/show"










  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)


   devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :views
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)



ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  # == Site Title
  #
  # Set the title that is displayed on the main layout
  # for each of the active admin pages.
  #
  config.site_title = "BarnPix.com"

  # Set the link url for the title. For example, to take
  # users to your main site. Defaults to no link.
  #
  config.site_title_link = "http://www.barnpix.com"

  # Set an optional image to be displayed for the header
  # instead of a string (overrides :site_title)
  #
  # Note: Recommended image height is 21px to properly fit in the header
  #
  # config.site_title_image = "/images/logo.png"

  # == Default Namespace
  #
  # Set the default namespace each administration resource
  # will be added to.
  #
  # eg:
  #   config.default_namespace = :hello_world
  #
  # This will create resources in the HelloWorld module and
  # will namespace routes to /hello_world/*
  #
  # To set no namespace by default, use:
  #   config.default_namespace = false
  #
  # Default:
  # config.default_namespace = :admin
  #
  # You can customize the settings for each namespace by using
  # a namespace block. For example, to change the site title
  # within a namespace:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.site_title = "Custom Admin Title"
  #   end
  #
  # This will ONLY change the title for the admin section. Other
  # namespaces will continue to use the main "site_title" configuration.

  # == User Authentication
  #
  # Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
  # method in a before filter of all controller actions to
  # ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # within the controller.
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!


  # == Current User
  #
  # Active Admin will associate actions with the current
  # user performing them.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # to return the currently logged in user.
  config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user


  # == Logging Out
  #
  # Active Admin displays a logout link on each screen. These
  # settings configure the location and method used for the link.
  #
  # This setting changes the path where the link points to. If it's
  # a string, the strings is used as the path. If it's a Symbol, we
  # will call the method to return the path.
  #
  # Default:
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path

  # This setting changes the http method used when rendering the
  # link. For example :get, :delete, :put, etc..
  #
  # Default:
  # config.logout_link_method = :get

  # == Root
  #
  # Set the action to call for the root path. You can set different
  # roots for each namespace.
  #
  # Default:
  # config.root_to = 'dashboard#index'

  # == Admin Comments
  #
  # Admin comments allow you to add comments to any model for admin use.
  # Admin comments are enabled by default.
  #
  # Default:
  # config.allow_comments = true
  #
  # You can turn them on and off for any given namespace by using a
  # namespace config block.
  #
  # Eg:
  #   config.namespace :without_comments do |without_comments|
  #     without_comments.allow_comments = false
  #   end


  # == Batch Actions
  #
  # Enable and disable Batch Actions
  #
  config.batch_actions = true


  # == Controller Filters
  #
  # You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
  # Active Admin resources and pages from here.
  #
  # config.before_filter :do_something_awesome


  # == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
  #
  # We recommend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
  # up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
  # and feel.
  #
  # To load a stylesheet:
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'

  # You can provide an options hash for more control, which is passed along to stylesheet_link_tag():
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_print_stylesheet.css', :media => :print
  #
  # To load a javascript file:
  #   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'


  # == CSV options
  #
  # Set the CSV builder separator (default is ",")
  # config.csv_column_separator = ','
  #
  # Set the CSV builder options (default is {})
  # config.csv_options = {}


  # == Menu System
  #
  # You can add a navigation menu to be used in your application, or configure a provided menu
  # 
  # To change the default utility navigation to show a link to your website & a logout btn
  # 
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
  #       menu.add label: "My Great Website", url: "http://www.mygreatwebsite.com", html_options: { target: :blank }
  #       admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  # If you wanted to add a static menu item to the default menu provided:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.build_menu :default do |menu|
  #       menu.add label: "My Great Website", url: "http://www.mygreatwebsite.com", html_options: { target: :blank }
  #     end
  #   end

  # == Download Links
  #
  # You can disable download links on resource listing pages,
  # or customize the formats shown per namespace/globally
  #
  # To disable/customize for the :admin namespace:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #
  #     # Disable the links entirely
  #     admin.download_links = false
  #
  #     # Only show XML & PDF options
  #     admin.download_links = [:xml, :pdf]
  #
  #   end


  # == Pagination
  #
  # Pagination is enabled by default for all resources.
  # You can control the default per page count for all resources here.
  #
  #config.default_per_page = 30


  # == Filters
  #
  # By default the index screen includes a “Filters” sidebar on the right 
  # hand side with a filter for each attribute of the registered model.
  # You can enable or disable them for all resources here.
  #
  # config.filters = true


end
```

Comment: What error is raised in the Heroku logs? Also, `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` should only be in your routes file once.

Comment: I am remove active admin and retrying setup so hpefully this works